# How to fix this error using messageui library in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, messageui

I used the messageui library in swift to create a mail composer, embedded into a button that opens the default mail app once clicked. However I keep getting this error once the mail app is opened.

Error:[PPT] Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.

Comment: Googling this error shows lots of people encountering it, but it seems to be a system-level error and does not actually affect the sending of mail. Does this cause any noticeable error behavior for you?

Comment: nope when I tap a button in my app it opens the default mail on a real iPhone and im able to receive emails and send them perfectly only that error message keeps showing up.

Comment: I'd say ignore it. Apple logs a lot of stuff that we can ignore -- sadly knowing which ones we can ignore is sometimes a challenge, but this seems to be one of them.

Comment: can you add some code? maybe with some print lines to frame what triggers the error?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has this issue, I seem to have found it. I had implemented `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` in the *MessagesViewController.m*,
but i did not call `[super viewDidAppear:animated]`. Adding the call to `super` fixed the missing touch events.

The problem seems unrelated to the CFMessagePort error, because those are still showing in the Xcode console.

Comment: It's nice that you fixed a problem _you_ were having, but this does not have anything to do with the problem that the _question_ was about.